# Error! Automatically add data in MVC 5 in action Create

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm getting an error.
I have 2 tables DonHang, Kho. DonHang link to Kho (DonHang.kid -> Kho.id)
I used code first from database in visual studio 2017 created models DonHang, Kho, class ShopDbContext.
I created controller Home in my project have action Create (using add data to table DonHang). But, when i use this action, website automatically adds data into table Kho and assigns new id for tabe DonHang, although in the project there is no action Create Kho.

I send code of project to everyone checking out
Thanks!

Model DonHang

```
[Table("DonHang")]
public partial class DonHang
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public int? uid { get; set; }

    public int? kid { get; set; }

    public int? soluong { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ngayxuat { get; set; }

    public int? khachhang { get; set; }

    public int? thanhtoan { get; set; }

    public int? no { get; set; }

    public string ghichu { get; set; }

    public int? thanhtien { get; set; }

    public virtual KhachHang KhachHang1 { get; set; }

    public virtual Kho Kho { get; set; }

    public virtual TaiKhoan TaiKhoan { get; set; }
}
```

Model Kho

```
[Table("Kho")]
public partial class Kho
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Kho()
    {
        DonHangs = new HashSet<DonHang>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }

    public int? uid { get; set; }

    public int? soluong { get; set; }

    public int? gianhap { get; set; }

    public int? giaxuat { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ngaynhap { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    public string tensanpham { get; set; }

    public string mota { get; set; }

    public int? phanloai { get; set; }

    public int? tinhtrang { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    public string donvi { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<DonHang> DonHangs { get; set; }

    public virtual TaiKhoan TaiKhoan { get; set; }
}
```

ShopDbContex

```
public partial class ShopDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ShopDbContext()
        : base("name=ShopDbContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<DonHang> DonHangs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<KhachHang> KhachHangs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Kho> Khoes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TaiKhoan> TaiKhoans { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<KhachHang>()
            .HasMany(e => e.DonHangs)
            .WithOptional(e => e.KhachHang1)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.khachhang);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Kho>()
            .HasMany(e => e.DonHangs)
            .WithOptional(e => e.Kho)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.kid);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TaiKhoan>()
            .HasMany(e => e.DonHangs)
            .WithOptional(e => e.TaiKhoan)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.uid);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TaiKhoan>()
            .HasMany(e => e.KhachHangs)
            .WithOptional(e => e.TaiKhoan)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.uid);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TaiKhoan>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Khoes)
            .WithOptional(e => e.TaiKhoan)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.uid);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(DonHang dh)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                dh.uid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UID"]);
                dh.khachhang = 3;
                dh.ghichu = "";
                dh.kid = 29;
                dh.ngayxuat = DateTime.Now;
                db.DonHangs.Add(dh);
                db.SaveChanges();
                TempData["Alert"] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Thêm khách hàng thành công.</div>";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

View
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJXU8.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your post, below:

```
[Table("DonHang")]
public partial class DonHang
{
    ...
    public int? kid { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Kho Kho { get; set; }

}
```

a DonHang can have 0 or 1 Kho. In other words, a DonHang can exist without a Kho. Therefore, in your controller Create Action, you can comment out or remove the following line and see if a Kho would still be created in the DB:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(DonHang dh)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            ...
            //dh.kid = 29;    //Comment out or remove this line
            ...
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Any value other than null that you assign to dh.Kid must have a corresponding k.Id in the Kho table. You cannot assign value 29 to dh.Kid without having a Kho with Id 29. I suspect EF is automatically creating a Kho with Id 29 when you try to insert a new DonHang. That works because all the fields of Kho table, except for the Id PK, are nullable.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I fixed it. Error in view.